How hidden Expected Revenue and Probability with odoo Plugin crm
how hidden odoo crm plugin fields with this code:
models.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, api, fields
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PrivacyConsent(models.Model):
    _name = "spekno.crm.privacy.consent"
    _description = "Privacy Consent"

    name = fields.Char("Nome Consenso", required=True)
    type = fields.Selection([('marketing', 'Marketing'), ('3rdparty', 'Terze Parti')], string="Tipo consenso")
    ext_ref = fields.Char("ID esterno")
    internal = fields.Boolean(string="Interno", default=False)
    active = fields.Boolean(string="Attivo", default=True)

class CrmLead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    my_text_field = fields.Text(string='Anagrafica suggerita')
    ext_portal = fields.Selection([('toshiko', 'Toshiko'), ('tcar', 'Tcar'), ('jeep', 'Jeep')],
                                  string="Portale di provenienza")
    ext_ref = fields.Char("Id Lead Portale", help="Codice lead Portale")
    privacy = fields.Many2many('spekno.crm.privacy.consent', 'crm_lead_privacy_consent_rel', string="Privacy",
                               tracking=True)
    ext_create_date = fields.Datetime(string="Data creazione su portale esterno")
    ext_customer_request = fields.Html(string="Richiesta Cliente Portale")
    suggested_partner_id = fields.Many2many('res.partner', 'crm_lead_suggested_partner_rel', string="Partner Suggeriti",
                                            tracking=True)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        lead = super(CrmLead, self).create(vals)
        success = lead.validate_contact_info()
        if not success:
            _logger.error('Failed to validate contact info for Lead ID: %s', lead.id)
        return lead

    def validate_contact_info(self):
        if not self:
            return False

        updated = False
        for lead in self:
            _logger.info('Starting validation for Lead ID: %s', lead.id)

            if lead.suggested_partner_id:
                suggested_partner_ids = lead.suggested_partner_id.ids
                partners = self.env['res.partner'].browse(suggested_partner_ids)

                for partner in partners:
                    if lead.phone and partner.phone != lead.phone:
                        _logger.info('Updating phone for Partner ID: %s', partner.id)
                        partner.phone = lead.phone
                        updated = True

                    if lead.email and partner.email != lead.email:
                        _logger.info('Updating email for Partner ID: %s', partner.id)
                        partner.email = lead.email
                        updated = True

        if updated:
            _logger.info('Contact info updated for Lead ID: %s', self.id)
            return True
        else:
            _logger.info('No updates necessary for Lead ID: %s', self.id)
            return True

view.xml:
<odoo>
   <data>
      <record id="action_validate_contact_info" model="ir.actions.server">
         <field name="name">Validate Contact Info</field>
         <field name="model_id" ref="crm.model_crm_lead" />
         <field name="state">code</field>
         <field name="code">model.validate_contact_info()</field>
      </record>
      <record id="crm_lead_view_form_lead_fields" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_lead_view_form" />
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='tag_ids']" position="after">
               <button name="%(action_validate_contact_info)d" string="Valida Anagrafica" type="action" class="oe_highlight" />
               <group name="my_section" style="{'invisible': [('some_field', '=', False)]}">
                  <field name="ext_portal" />
                  <field name="ext_ref" />
                  <field name="privacy" />
                  <field name="ext_create_date" />
                  <field name="ext_customer_request" />
                  <field name="my_text_field" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo testo qui" />
               </group>
            </xpath>
         </field>
      </record>
   </data>
</odoo>


Please revise your question and provide more details.
If your English is not fully sufficient to accomplish this, please use one of the many useful translation tools such as ChatGPT or DeepL.
